# How to remove Active Content from uploaded PDF documents?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfium

I developed a kind of job application website and I only now realized that by allowing the upload of PDF files I'm at risk of receiving PDF documents containing encrypted data, active content (e.g. JavaScript, PostScript), and external references.

What could I use to sanitize or re-build the content of every PDF files uploaded by users?

I want that the companies that will later review the uploaded resumes are able to open the resumes from their browsers without putting them at risk..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to flatten or sanitise a PDF that can be done using using GhostScript in safer mode requires just one pass:-

For a Windows user it will be as "simple" as using new 9.55 command

```
"c:\path to gs9.55\bin\GSwin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNEWPDF -o "Output.pdf" "Input.pdf"
```

for others replace gs9.55\bin\GSwin64c with version 9.55 GS command

It is not a fast method e.g. around 40ppm is not uncommon, thus 4 pages is about 6 seconds to be reprinted, however, a 400 page document could take 10 minutes.

Advantages the file size is often smaller once any redundant content is removed. Images and font reconstruction may save storage, e.g. a 100 MB file may be reduced to 30 MB but that is a general bonus, not an aim.

JavaScript actions are usually discarded, However links such as bookmarks are usually retained, so be cautious as the result can still have rogue hyperlinks.

The next best suggestion is two passes via PostScript as discussed here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103323/effectiveness-of-flattening-a-pdf-to-remove-malware

```
GS[win64c] -sDEVICE=ps2write -o "%temp%\temp.ps" "Input.pdf"
GS[win64c] -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o "Output.pdf" "%temp%\temp.ps"
```

But there is no proof that its any different or more effective than the one line approach.

Finally the strictest method of all, is burst the pdf into image only pages then stitch the images back into a single pdf and  concurrently run OCR to reconstruct a searchable PDF (drops bookmarks). That can also be done using Ghostscript enabled  with Tesseract.

Note:- visible external hyperlinks may then still be reactivated due to the pdf readers native ability.